# Javascript Objects in Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to use the Ajax File Upload as featured here: http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

As you can see, I need to create a qq.FileUploader object to initialize the script. However, I need to be able to dynamically create this objects without knowing the IDs of the elements. I've tried creating something like this:

```
var uploader, i = 0;
$(".file-upload").each(function() {
    $e = $(this);
    i++;
    uploader[i] = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: $(this)[0],
        action: 'uploadfile.php',
        allowedExtensions: ['doc', 'docx', 'pdf'],
        multiple: false,
        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
            $($e).siblings('input').val(responseJSON.newfilename);
        }
    });
});
```

I've learned that the `[i]` part I have added breaks the script, because I cannot have objects inside of an array.

Is there another way I can create this objects dynamically? They need to all have a unique name, otherwise the `onComplete` function gets overwritten for all of them. I experimented with using `eval()`, but I can't seem to make it work correctly.

Comment: `$e = $(this);` so you don't need to re-wrap it later. `$e.siblings('input').val(responseJSON.newfilename);` also `$(this)[0]` is redundant. just use `element: this,` also you can remove `i++;` and just put `uploader[++i] = new qq.FileUploader({`... scratch that.. you can change `$(".file-upload").each(function() {` to `$(".file-upload").each(function(i) {` and leave out the variable i and increment all together.   [**tl;rd**](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/XqZUS/)

Comment: [here is a demo with uploader.push() for kicks](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/XqZUS/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare `uploader` as an array first :

```
var uploader = [];
```

Because you declared the variable without defining it, it has the default value of `undefined` , and your code was translated into something like `undefined[i]` which triggers an error.

Comment: i feel like assigning something to the array in this fashion is a strange idea, would rather use uploader.push()

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push like you would with an Array??? :P

Comment: what exactly do you mean, @rlemon?

Comment: You are advocating using Array.push; yet your answer assigns the variable as a object.

Comment: @rlemon because both options are valid. Either [] and uploader.push(), or {} and uploader.[i] = ....

Comment: But they are in fact doing different things. I think in this case the OP did in fact want to use the push method. There were a number of other mistakes that were also made which would indicate to me a very loose understanding of what it is he is doing.

Comment: Using `.push()` is nice but there's really nothing at all wrong with assigning to a numerically-indexed property (that is, an array cell) directly.  The language is explicitly designed to make that work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Has to be something like

```
var uploader = {};
```

or else uploader is null and you cannot assign anything to it.

**EDIT**:

So there're two opitions, in my opinion, if one wants to have an array than it makes sense to declare one, `var uploader = [];` and then use the `uploader.push()` method or define it as an object `var uploader = {};` and just do `uploader[i] = ...`.

It is also possible to do the latter with an a array, but in the latter case I see no point in maintaining the counter (`i`).

Comment: I didn't downvote, because this answer is not really *wrong*, but it's more likely that the OP wants a real array and not just an object as the indexes are numeric. Thus, `var uploader = [];` is probably a better answer.

Comment: @Pointy I agree, but then array.push() sounds more appropriate to me, as I already pointed out above.

Comment: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'`

Comment: @rlemon, that's my point exactly, if you declare something to be an array, than it makes sense to use array-specific functions such as push(). If you want to just do something[i] = 'whatever', than it's fine to just have an object.

Comment: @Qnan well except that an array will automatically maintain the `.length` property regardless of how properties (with numeric "names") are added.

Comment: @Pointy I'm not saying one can't do that, just that there's no point in maintaining the counter.

Comment: @Qnan yes I agree with you on that, especially since `.each()` passes the index in as a parameter :-)